# How to draw a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to create a vector in R an show it graphically.

I want to create a vector in R an show it graphically. I can create a vector, but I don't know how to graph it?
I have tryed the vector3d function in matlib, but I don't get it to work.

In most functions I have tried, you are supposed to give the angle. But when working with vectors, that shouldn't be nessesary.

I just want a simple arrow as output. As simple as possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are more likely to get help if you post what you've tried that doesn't work than simply asking for code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with the `arrows`  function:

```
x <- c(0,2)
y <- c(1,2)
plot(x,y)
arrows(x[1],y[1],x[2],y[2])
```

For 3D-Vectors check the plot3D package. It has a function `arrows3D` which is capable of plotting single 3D vectors. For further information on this package check the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/plot3D.pdf)

```
arrows3D (0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3,
          colvar = NULL, phi = 40, theta = 40,
          col = NULL, NAcol = "white", breaks = NULL,
          colkey = NULL, panel.first = NULL,
          clim = NULL, clab = NULL, bty = "b", type = "triangle", 
          add = FALSE, plot = TRUE)
```

Comment: Looks like OP is looking to plot a single vector.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a nice Arrow :)

Comment: But I this is what I think of as an arrow with coordinats of x and y. I thought that a vector was just an arrow. Like for instance (2,5) . Which means 2 steps to the right and 5 steps up. From where ever I am. I whish there was a method I could use to draw a vector, starting in 0, and then (2 ,5) . But this is also ok. I think I can use it.

Comment: @dobby aww sorry, i'm afraid it's not this simple. As far as i know you need to draw it like this. Maybe some plot packages have this function, but i don't know it then. Still, if this helped you sufficiently, you can mark this question as answered with the green tick. If not, don't do it then. I give this hint to new users, since some don't recognize the function, so don't feel forced if you don't want to.